# Linking to another html page in Google Apps Script Not working in sandbox 'IFRAME'

Tags: html, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script: Using `NATIVE` sandbox mode:

[Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script/16697525#16697525) is working fine.

But when using `IFRAME` sandbox mode:

[Unable to get links working in Google Apps Script when using sandbox mode of "IFRAME"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383419/unable-to-get-links-working-in-google-apps-script-when-using-sandbox-mode-of-if)

As per the above SO post I tried using `target="_blank"`. As expected, when the link is clicked the page opens in a new window.

However -

Using  `target="_parent"` in Chrome opens a new window each time, but Firefox is not working. According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions `target="_parent"` is not supported by `HTML Service` — this is probably why it behaves like `target="_blank"`.

Using `target="_self"` in both Chrome and Firefox results in the first click opening in the same window but subsequent clicks bring up a blank page.

I want the page to load in the same window as my Apps script, as would occur when using `target="_self"` in an anchor on an unrestricted web page.

plz help me.

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour with <a>nchors with target="_self", and would also like to know whether there is any solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a doc error needs to fix with Google when using "SandBoxMode=IFRAME" currently. See [Can't call a server function with a form with input type="file" when using SandBoxMode=IFRAME.](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4610&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

I've tested it works now by setting the `HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE`
instead of working when `HtmlService.SandboxMode` is set to `Iframe`. Also reference to this related issue [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036739/google-script-for-uploading-file-not-working/29042739#29042739)

Answer (score 1):

When using `IFRAME` sandbox mode, for `<a>`nchors to open in the same tab or window, `target="_top"` must be specified. Support for this was added to Google Apps Script in the latter half of 2015. Before this time unexpected behaviour resulted.  From [a Google Apps Script developer blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/google-apps-script-update-to-htmlservice.html):

> We have been working hard to improve IFRAME sandbox mode and have
>   added many features since then, including: Firefox support, file
>   uploads, **top navigation support**, and improved Google Picker API
>   support.